# Using compound, I got an error on update when using validatesPresenceOf

Tags: node.js, compoundjs, jugglingdb

I'm creating an app with **compound** and **mongodb**. Compound use jugglingdb and jugglingdb-mongodb to connect to mongodb.

I generated a crud for a client using the scaffolding of compound. Then, I added `Client.validatesPresenceOf('name');` to app/models/client.js

```
module.exports = function (compound, Client) {
  Client.validatesPresenceOf('name');
};
```

On create, it work, but on update it fail.

I also tried adding the validation to db/schema.js, but I got the same error.

This is the error I got

> /Users/camilo/Documents/Pruebas/Nodejs/interno2/node_modules/jugglingdb-mongodb/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:529
>           throw err;
>                 ^
>   Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
>       at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (http.js:708:11)
>       at ServerResponse.res.setHeader (/Users/camilo/Documents/Pruebas/Nodejs/interno2/node_modules/express/node_modules/connect/lib/patch.js:59:22)
>       at ServerResponse.res.set.res.header (/Users/camilo/Documents/Pruebas/Nodejs/interno2/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:518:10)
>       at ServerResponse.res.location (/Users/camilo/Documents/Pruebas/Nodejs/interno2/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:649:8)
>       at ServerResponse.res.redirect (/Users/camilo/Documents/Pruebas/Nodejs/interno2/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:691:8)
>       at Controller.Helpers.redirect (/Users/camilo/Documents/Pruebas/Nodejs/interno2/node_modules/compound/node_modules/kontroller/lib/helpers.js:168:14)
>       at eval (eval at  (/Users/camilo/Documents/Pruebas/Nodejs/interno2/node_modules/compound/node_modules/kontroller/lib/base.js:157:17), :97:38)
>       at Object.html (/Users/camilo/Documents/Pruebas/Nodejs/interno2/node_modules/compound/node_modules/kontroller/lib/helpers.js:43:17)
>       at eval (eval at  (/Users/camilo/Documents/Pruebas/Nodejs/interno2/node_modules/compound/node_modules/kontroller/lib/base.js:157:17), :93:20)
>       at Controller.respondTo (/Users/camilo/Documents/Pruebas/Nodejs/interno2/node_modules/compound/node_modules/kontroller/lib/helpers.js:38:5)
>       at action.cliente.destroy.format.json.send.code (eval at  (/Users/camilo/Documents/Pruebas/Nodejs/interno2/node_modules/compound/node_modules/kontroller/lib/base.js:157:17), :84:9)
>       at ModelConstructor. (/Users/camilo/Documents/Pruebas/Nodejs/interno2/node_modules/jugglingdb/lib/model.js:827:33)
>       at ModelConstructor.next (/Users/camilo/Documents/Pruebas/Nodejs/interno2/node_modules/jugglingdb/lib/hooks.js:48:18)
>       at ModelConstructor. (/Users/camilo/Documents/Pruebas/Nodejs/interno2/node_modules/jugglingdb/lib/model.js:826:38)
>       at ModelConstructor.next (/Users/camilo/Documents/Pruebas/Nodejs/interno2/node_modules/jugglingdb/lib/hooks.js:48:18)
>       at /Users/camilo/Documents/Pruebas/Nodejs/interno2/node_modules/jugglingdb/lib/model.js:825:30
>       at /Users/camilo/Documents/Pruebas/Nodejs/interno2/node_modules/jugglingdb-mongodb/lib/mongodb.js:249:9
>       at /Users/camilo/Documents/Pruebas/Nodejs/interno2/node_modules/jugglingdb-mongodb/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/collection.js:703:14
>       at null. (/Users/camilo/Documents/Pruebas/Nodejs/interno2/node_modules/jugglingdb-mongodb/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/db.js:1709:18)
>       at g (events.js:175:14)
>       at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:106:17)
>       at Server.Base._callHandler (/Users/camilo/Documents/Pruebas/Nodejs/interno2/node_modules/jugglingdb-mongodb/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/base.js:130:25)
>       at /Users/camilo/Documents/Pruebas/Nodejs/interno2/node_modules/jugglingdb-mongodb/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:464:24
>       at MongoReply.parseBody (/Users/camilo/Documents/Pruebas/Nodejs/interno2/node_modules/jugglingdb-mongodb/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/responses/mongo_reply.js:132:5)
>       at null. (/Users/camilo/Documents/Pruebas/Nodejs/interno2/node_modules/jugglingdb-mongodb/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/server.js:410:22)
>       at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
>       at null. (/Users/camilo/Documents/Pruebas/Nodejs/interno2/node_modules/jugglingdb-mongodb/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection_pool.js:190:13)
>       at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:98:17)
>       at Socket. (/Users/camilo/Documents/Pruebas/Nodejs/interno2/node_modules/jugglingdb-mongodb/node_modules/mongodb/lib/mongodb/connection/connection.js:382:22)
>       at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
>       at Socket. (_stream_readable.js:699:14)
>       at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:92:17)
>       at emitReadable_ (_stream_readable.js:382:10)
>       at emitReadable (_stream_readable.js:377:5)
>       at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:142:7)
>       at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:112:10)
>       at TCP.onread (net.js:511:21)

**Versions:**

- nodejs: 0.10.1
- compoundjs: 1.1.5-21
- jubblingdb: 0.2.0-27
- jugglingdb-mongodb: 0.0.4-1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a bug on jubblingdb 0.2.0-27. The author updated it to 0.2.0-28 and the problem was solved.